# Send a message to friend via Facebook SDK from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, swift2, facebook-messenger

I heard that the chat API for Facebook was deprecated a couple years back but I'm wondering if by using the new messenger API, it's possible to send a message to a friend via Facebook. The user logs in with the login button and gets their info with a graph request and now I want to send a test message.

Here is the code to login (works)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

var currentUserIDString : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let facebookLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    facebookLoginButton.delegate = self
    facebookLoginButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(facebookLoginButton)

    let button : UIButton = FBSDKMessengerShareButton.circularButtonWithStyle(FBSDKMessengerShareButtonStyle.Blue, width: 80)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "shareTest", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 40, 390, 80, 80)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}

// other methods

}
```

Login delegate, getting user's info (also works)

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {


    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender, email"])

    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        else if let result = result {

            self.currentUserIDString = result["id"] as? String
            print(self.currentUserIDString)

        }
    }

}
```

Share method, having some trouble here... the code within the parameters dictionary and fields is probably incorrect, but the Facebook docs are pretty poor so it's hard to find good examples.

```
func shareTestGraphRequest() {

    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {

        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("read_page_mailbox") {

            //establish param dictionary here
            let parameterDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            parameterDictionary.setObject("This is a test message, I'm building an app!", forKey: "message")
            parameterDictionary.setObject(self.currentUserIDString!, forKey: "from")
            parameterDictionary.setObject([], forKey: "to")

            let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/{message-id}", parameters: parameterDictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "POST")

            graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in


            }

        }
    }

    else {

        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(["read_page_mailbox"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }

            else if let result = result {
                print(result)

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using Facebook messenger SDK integration you can send message to your friends. But this just allows to send media like image, GIF, video and you can not send plain text through this SDK.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for external message feature but your answer satisfied. As I understand there is not any alternative to do that